# Scheme How to print a list without parenthesis?

Tags: scheme

I'm new user in Scheme. I just want to know how to print a list without parenthesis.

Example:

> (define mylist '(a b c d f g))
>
> (display mylist)
>
> (a b c d f g)

I want to print out in the following format:

> a b c d f g

Answer (score 1):

The only way to print values is to use a printing procedure like `display`. Thus:

```scm
(display 'a)       ; ==> <unspecified>, prints the string "a" to the screen
(display '(a b c)) ; ==> <unspecified>, prints the string "(a b c)" to the screen
```

With that in mind you can print a list by printing it's elements:

```scm
(define (display-list lst)
  (let loop ((lst lst))
    (when (pair? lst)
      (display (car lst))
      (display " ")
      (loop (cdr lst))))
  (newline))
```

Or we can use higher order procedures:

```scm
(define (display-list lst)
  (for-each (lambda (what)
              (display what)
              (display " "))
            lst)
  (newline))
```

They both work similar to display. They print the list and evaluate to the same return as `newline` does, which is an unspecified implementation dependent value. In most implementations its a value that is never printed.

```scm
(define mylist '(a b c d f g))
(display-list mylist) ; ==> <unspecified>, prints "a b c d f g \n" to the screen
```

Keep in mind this will only omit the parentheses of the outer list, thus:

```scm
(display-list '((a) (b))) ; ==> <unspecified>, prints "(a) (b) \n" to the screen
```